# Apache rewrite rule causes "too many redirects" for JS and CSS files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a project with a custom CMS (which is written by someone else). There's an existing `.htaccess` file with some conditions and rewrite rules, one of which directs requests to the `index.php` file. This file loads the CMS object, and calls a method to check if the URL leads to an existing CMS page. If it doesn't, the user is redirected to a 404 page.

The CMS also allows you to build custom modules on top of the base CMS functionality. Usually this is used for user management and stuff like that, but for this project the client wants to be able to build a knowledge base with hundreds of knowledge base items, which in the CMS would become a giant mess. I've now built a custom module for these items, and they also store a slug. I want the URLs to be `/knowledgebase/items/item-slug`, but with the existing configuration this would lead to a redirect to the 404 page because, as far as the CMS is aware, the `item-slug` doesn't lead to an existing CMS page. This is the current rewrite section in the `.htaccess` file.

```
# Enable the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /domain.tld

# SSL Redirect 301 transfer the current request.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# never rewrite for existing files, and links
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For Friendly URLs
RewriteRule ^knowledgebase/items/(.*)$ index.php?knowledge_item_slug=$1 # my own RewriteRule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

In index.php I've added the following lines to check if a custom knowledgebase item needs to be shown

```
if (isset($_GET['knowledge_item_slug']) && $_GET['knowledge_item_slug'] !== '') {
    include_once(__DIR__ . '/components/knowledgebase_item.php');
    exit(0);
}
```

This works fine, going to `knowledgebase/items/test` loads the test item as it should. With this rule added however, CSS and JS files can no longer be found after a hard reload (clearing the cache) and cause `net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` errors in the console.

I've modified the rule to `RewriteRule ^kennisbank/items/(.*)$ index.php?knowledge_item_slug=$1 [C]` (basically just added the `[C]` flag) and now the item detail page works, but any other page causes the error `The requested URL /domain.tld/page was not found on this server.`

I've also tried placing `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php` above my own RewriteRule (without the `[L]` flag, obviously), but then my own one doesn't work at all.

I'm not too familiar with Apache rewrites, any idea what's causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you have 2 `RewriteRule` rules after checking for non-file and non-directory in `RewriteCond`. Only immediate next `RewriteRule` is affected by one or more `RewriteCond` hence last rule executes *without* any conditions that routes every request including css/js/images to `index.php`.

You can have your .htaccess as this:

```
# Enable the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /domain.tld

# SSL Redirect 301 transfer the current request.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# never rewrite for existing files, and links
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# For Friendly URLs
RewriteRule ^knowledgebase/items/(.*)$ index.php?knowledge_item_slug=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**Do-nothing** rule `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` will skip any rules below that line for the conditions above i.e. non-file and non-directory.